# Amazon s3 in mac osx?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Any tutorials or samples available for amazon s3 in mac os x?
Just needed a sample for the s3 simple upload download operation.
Searched a lot for api.but not available!!
Found custom one by Tom Anderson.But I cannot make it work.
Is there any workaround ?Looking for tutorials or source samples?

Comment: mac osX Programming!!! Objective C

Comment: Note:I found ios api there in AWS website.But nothing for the OS X devolopment

Comment: I use the AWS S3 files for Mac OSX and it works great. Just copy the Amazon.S3 folder including subfolders and the include folder into your Xcode project and you should be able to import the necessary classes required to do upload/download. You may have to edit a few files from using UIKit to Appkit, but that should be the only problem. There is an example (S3uploader) for S3 upload in the samples folder in the latest release of the AWS. Cheers, Trond

Comment: @Trond:Can i hav some working samples??

Comment: @TrondKristiansen : which files are you using for doing this??i(aws for mac??).can you please provide more info??

Comment: Just download the files at AWS: http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforios/ , Copy the folders I mentioned earlier and take a look at the sample S3Uploader

Comment: @TrondKristiansen : K i download the files and copied the files and added to a mac application but gettin some include files missing (like ../AmazonSDKUtil.h)..What to do??

Comment: @TrondKristiansen: what about the include files the whole folder or jus the s3 part??

Comment: You just have to remove the ../

Comment: It really works (using the iOS SDK in a Mac project with minor modifications) - I've made a minimal github project if you need a working example: [https://github.com/viktorbenei/AmazonS3-ios-sdk-in-osx-project](https://github.com/viktorbenei/AmazonS3-ios-sdk-in-osx-project)

Comment: Plz visit : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369602/how-to-upload-a-uiimage-to-s3-with-aws-ios-sdk-v2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19478904/nsurlsession-and-amazon-s3-uploads

Comment: Plz visit : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369602/how-to-upload-a-uiimage-to-s3-with-aws-ios-sdk-v2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19478904/nsurlsession-and-amazon-s3-uploads

Answer (score -1):

From the command-line the [aws-cli](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) is the easiest way to upload to / download from S3.

See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html

For programmatic access, available SDKs are here: http://aws.amazon.com/tools/

Comment: There are no Cocoa SDKs listed in the link you have provided. As far as I can tell, the closest thing to a native AWS SDK on Mac is the C++ integration.