# How to upload a UIImage to S3 with AWS iOS SDK v2

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, uiimage

The README page in Github (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios-v2) already has an example to upload an image, from the file path URL:

```
AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
uploadRequest.bucket = yourBucket;
uploadRequest.key = yourKey;
uploadRequest.body = yourDataURL; // <<<< this is a NSURL
uploadRequest.contentLength = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:fileSize];
```

But, what if I only have a `UIImage` in memory (without file path)?
Is it possible to upload a `UIImage` (or it's `NSData`) to `S3` using the `SDK`?

Would it be easier to manually use the HTTP API (using something like AFNetworking)?

Comment: check my updated answer (new people who see this): http://stackoverflow.com/a/38897748/6042879

Comment: Note I'm not asking how to save the image to a file so it can be uploaded. The question is about uploading the image WITHOUT having to create a file (in my case for security reasons, since users can access the file system)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that AWSiOSSDKv2 don't have support to upload images from memory at this moment :(

From a [Github issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios-v2/issues/6):

> The decision to accept only file NSURLs was driven by the following
>   factors:
>
> 1. Since v1, the pause / resume features require the input to be
>      files. It's not possible to recover NSData and retry the transfer when
>      the app is killed.
> 2. The background transfer on iOS 7 and above only
>      supports files. Currently, we don't support background transfer, but
>      we are planning to support it in the future. We considered accepting
>      an NSData and internally persisting the data to a temporary directory.
> 3. We decided not to include this in 2.0 release because if the NSData is
>      backed by a file, it doubles the disk usage for the data. Also,
>      developers have to deal with disk related errors when using
>      S3TransferManager. Even though we decided not to accept NSData in 2.0
>      release, we are open for your feedback. If this is a feature you want
>      to see in the future release, please create a new issue with the
>      feature request.

```

Comment: Thanks for updating...was curious about this.

Comment: but if i want to upload video with v2  do i have to write nsdata in to a fie and upload  ??

Answer (score 19):

Even though AWSiOSSDKv2 doesn't support uploading images from memory, you can save it as a file and then upload it.

```
//image you want to upload
UIImage* imageToUpload = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imagetoupload"]; 

//convert uiimage to 
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", dateKey]];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToUpload) writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

NSURL* fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

//upload the image
AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
uploadRequest.body = fileUrl;
uploadRequest.bucket = AWS_BUCKET_NAME;
uploadRequest.key = @"yourkey";
uploadRequest.contentType = @"image/png";
[[transferManager upload:thumbNailUploadRequest] continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
    if(task.error == nil) {
        NSLog(@"woot");
    }
    return nil;
}];
```

Comment: *For some reason this prefix isn't included in the file path* - you should try ```[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]``` instead!

Comment: May I suggest that in my case I also deleted the file after upload using `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];`

Comment: while I use this code it's not uploading whole data. It's upload certain amount data and then it's stop and get error.  any idea?

Comment: Remember to #import <AWSS3TransferManager.h> and <AWSCore.h>. Also, I had to change BFExectutor to AWSExecutor, and BFTask to AWSTask. Great answer Rick, helped a lot!

Comment: how can I generate the file permissions ?

Comment: this is work for me -     uploadRequest.ACL = AWSS3BucketCannedACLPublicRead;

Comment: check my updated answer (new people who see this): http://stackoverflow.com/a/38897748/6042879

Answer (score 3):

You can apparently do it with "presigned URLs"

```
- (void)uploadImageToS3: (UIImage *)image {
  NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7);

  AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest *getPreSignedURLRequest = [AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest new];
  getPreSignedURLRequest.bucket = @"bucket-name";
  getPreSignedURLRequest.key = @"image-name.jpg";
  getPreSignedURLRequest.HTTPMethod = AWSHTTPMethodPUT;
  getPreSignedURLRequest.expires = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3600];

  NSString *fileContentTypeString = @"text/plain";
  getPreSignedURLRequest.contentType = fileContentTypeString;

  [[[AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder defaultS3PreSignedURLBuilder] getPreSignedURL:getPreSignedURLRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {

    if (task.error) {
      NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
    } else {

      NSURL *presignedURL = task.result;
      NSLog(@"upload presignedURL is \n%@", presignedURL);

      NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:presignedURL];
      request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;
      [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
      [request setValue:fileContentTypeString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

      NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:imageData completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        if (error) {
          NSLog(@"Upload errer: %@", error);
        }
        NSLog(@"Done");
      }];

      [uploadTask resume];
    }

    return nil;

  }];
}
```

Documented in the S3 docs for v2 SDK at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html#use-pre-signed-urls-to-transfer-objects-in-the-background

Its a bit of a mess with nested completion blocks, but the gist is you request a url, then when that returns you start an upload task. This was for a prototype test, not polished code. You should check the status code on the upload instead of just the error.

Answer (score 2):

## **This is an updated answer so people don't have to figure it out themselves (like me) :D**

Import the proper files (download it [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html))

```
#import <AWSCore/AWSCore.h>
#import <AWSS3TransferManager.h>
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
       identityPoolId:@"us-east-1:*******-******-*****-*****-*****"];

    AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                                     credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
}
```

I used a button to know when the user wants to upload the file

```
- (void)upload{
    
    //convert uiimage to
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@".png"]];
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(YOUR_UIIMAGE) writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    
    NSURL* fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    
    //upload the image
    AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
    uploadRequest.body = fileUrl;
    uploadRequest.bucket = @"YOUR_BUCKET_NAME";
    uploadRequest.key = @"YOUR_FOLDER_NAME (if you have one)/NEW_IMAGE_NAME.png";
    uploadRequest.contentType = @"image/png";
    uploadRequest.ACL = AWSS3BucketCannedACLPublicRead;
    
    AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];
    
    [[transferManager upload:uploadRequest] continueWithExecutor:[AWSExecutor mainThreadExecutor]
                                                       withBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
                                        if (task.error != nil) {
                                            NSLog(@"%s %@","Error uploading :", uploadRequest.key);
                                        }else { NSLog(@"Upload completed"); }
                                            return nil;
                                        }];
}
```

Helpfull links:

[AWS Documnetion](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html)

[YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WZ54fH8AFUk)

## Hopefully this helps someone out!

Comment: Aren't you saving it to a file still ?

Answer (score 2):

In the [current version of the SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/how-to-transfer-files-with-transfer-utility.html) you can use `AWSS3TransferUtility` and then it does everything for you.

```
func uploadData() {

   let data: Data = Data() // Data to be uploaded

   let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()
      expression.progressBlock = {(task, progress) in
         DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
           // Do something e.g. Update a progress bar.
        })
   }

   var completionHandler: AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock?
   completionHandler = { (task, error) -> Void in
      DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
         // Do something e.g. Alert a user for transfer completion.
         // On failed uploads, `error` contains the error object.
      })
   }

   let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()

   transferUtility.uploadData(data,
        bucket: "YourBucket",
        key: "YourFileName",
        contentType: "text/plain",
        expression: expression,
        completionHandler: completionHandler).continueWith {
           (task) -> AnyObject! in
               if let error = task.error {
                  print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
               }

               if let _ = task.result {
                  // Do something with uploadTask.
               }
               return nil;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can sand image without saving image to the temporary folder in the iPhone Amazon iOS v2 gives such option as well.

In this code `logFile.body` it is `NSData`.

This code will help you my friend.

```
AWSS3PutObjectRequest *logFile = [AWSS3PutObjectRequest new];
  logFile.bucket = uploadTokenData_.bucket;
  logFile.key = key;
  logFile.contentType = contentType;
  logFile.body = data_;
  logFile.contentLength = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[data_ length]];

AWSS3 *S3 = [[AWSS3 alloc] initWithConfiguration:[AWSCredentialsProvider runServiceWithStsCredential]];

AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [[AWSS3TransferManager alloc] initWithS3:S3];

[[transferManager.s3 putObject:logFile] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task)
{

  NSLog(@"Error : %@", task.error);
  if (task.error == nil)
  {
    NSLog(@"Uploadet");
  }
}
```

Comment: Even in v2 the body property is still an NSURL you can't pass it NSData.

Answer (score 0):

With **AWSS3TransferUtility** you can upload any data type, also AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest is **deprecated** now, here is the code sample to upload jpeg but can be converted for any data type:

[Code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240317/swift-aws-s3-upload-image-from-photo-library-and-download-it/54899370#54899370)