# Swift - AWS S3 Upload Image from Photo Library and download it

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3

I've looked many amazon docs but didn't find enough information to upload and download images to S3 using Swift.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After doing many research I've got this working,

```
import AWSS3
import AWSCore
```

**Upload:**

I assume you have implemented `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` already.

**Step 1:**

- Create variable for holding url:

  ```
  var imageURL = NSURL()
  ```
- Create upload completion handler obj:

  ```
  var uploadCompletionHandler: AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock?
  ```

**Step 2:** Get Image URL from `imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)`:

- Set value of `imageURL` in this delegate method:

  ```
  func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]){

      //getting details of image
      let uploadFileURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL

      let imageName = uploadFileURL.lastPathComponent
      let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first! as String

      // getting local path
      let localPath = (documentDirectory as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(imageName!)


      //getting actual image
      let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
      let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
      data!.writeToFile(localPath, atomically: true)

      let imageData = NSData(contentsOfFile: localPath)!
      imageURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: localPath)

      picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
  }
  ```

**Step 3:** Call this `uploadImage` method after `imageURL` set to Upload Image to your bucket:

```
func uploadImage(){

    //defining bucket and upload file name
    let S3BucketName: String = "bucketName"
    let S3UploadKeyName: String = "public/testImage.jpg"


    let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()
    expression.uploadProgress = {(task: AWSS3TransferUtilityTask, bytesSent: Int64, totalBytesSent: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend: Int64) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            let progress = Float(totalBytesSent) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToSend)
            print("Progress is: \(progress)")
        })
    }

    self.uploadCompletionHandler = { (task, error) -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            if ((error) != nil){
                print("Failed with error")
                print("Error: \(error!)");
            }
            else{
                print("Sucess")
            }
        })
    }

    let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.defaultS3TransferUtility()

    transferUtility.uploadFile(imageURL, bucket: S3BucketName, key: S3UploadKeyName, contentType: "image/jpeg", expression: expression, completionHander: uploadCompletionHandler).continueWithBlock { (task) -> AnyObject! in
        if let error = task.error {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        if let exception = task.exception {
            print("Exception: \(exception.description)")
        }
        if let _ = task.result {
            print("Upload Starting!")
        }

        return nil;
    }
}
```

**Download:**

```
func downloadImage(){

    var completionHandler: AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadCompletionHandlerBlock?

    let S3BucketName: String = "bucketName"
    let S3DownloadKeyName: String = "public/testImage.jpg"

    let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadExpression()
    expression.downloadProgress = {(task: AWSS3TransferUtilityTask, bytesSent: Int64, totalBytesSent: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend: Int64) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            let progress = Float(totalBytesSent) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToSend)
            print("Progress is: \(progress)")
        })
    }

    completionHandler = { (task, location, data, error) -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            if ((error) != nil){
                print("Failed with error")
                print("Error: \(error!)")
            }
            else{
                //Set your image
                var downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
        })
    }

    let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.defaultS3TransferUtility()

    transferUtility.downloadToURL(nil, bucket: S3BucketName, key: S3DownloadKeyName, expression: expression, completionHander: completionHandler).continueWithBlock { (task) -> AnyObject! in
        if let error = task.error {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        if let exception = task.exception {
            print("Exception: \(exception.description)")
        }
        if let _ = task.result {
            print("Download Starting!")
        }
        return nil;
    }

}
```

[Ref. for upload image](http://jzorz.com/aws-s3-swift-upload-image-from-camera-or-photolibrary/)

[Ref. for download image](http://jzorz.com/aws-s3-swift-download-image/)

Many thanks to [jzorz](http://jzorz.com/author/jzorz/)

Comment: how did you manage to get it work? I followed the same tutorial but it doesn't work for me. tons of things print in my console and I do not know where to start with...

Comment: in fact, i downloaded their project from github, and change bucket and keys to mine, but fail to upload.....

Comment: Have you tries my answer,after testing it I have uploaded here?

Comment: yes I did. but it is not working for me. no idea where is it wrong also. don't even know where to start with....

Comment: Right, there is no good documentation available. I thought this may help someone.

Comment: Glad this worked for you Zaid! Jo3birdtalk what kind of errors were you seeing?

Comment: This doesn't work for Swfit3 can someone update the examples?, for example expression.uploadProgress gives error, saying there is no member uploadProgress.

Comment: How to make photo upload in public environment. Because right now whenever i am trying to upload photo on S3 bucket it will store in private environment.

Comment: I am getting this error.. it goes on hence the dots.                                  
                          Error: Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSS3TransferUtilityErrorDomain Code=2 "(null)" UserInfo={Server=AmazonS3....................

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to download the image, this is a much more concise and correct way to do it:

```
func downloadImage(bucketName: String, fileName: String, completion: (image: UIImage?, error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.defaultS3TransferUtility()

    transferUtility.downloadDataFromBucket(bucketName, key: fileName, expression: nil) { (task, url, data, error) in
        var resultImage: UIImage?

        if let data = data {
            resultImage = UIImage(data: data)
        }

        completion(image: resultImage, error: error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func uploadFile(with resource: String, type: String) {
        let key = "\(resource).\(type)"
        let localImagePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: resource, ofType: type)
        let localImageUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: localImagePath!)
        let transferManager1 = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()
        let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()
        self.uploadCompletionHandler = { (task, error) -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2, execute: {
                if ((error) != nil){
                    print("Failed with error")
                    print("Error: \(error!)");
                }
                else{
                    print("Sucess")
                }
            })
        }
        let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()
        transferUtility.uploadFile(localImageUrl, bucket: "", key: key, contentType: "video/mov", expression: expression, completionHandler: uploadCompletionHandler).continueWith { (task) -> AnyObject? in
            if let error = task.error {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            if let _ = task.result {
                print("Upload Starting!")
            }
            return nil;
        }
    }
@IBAction func uplaodVideo(){
    uploadFile(with: "random", type: "mov")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers were really helpful to me, but they're quite outdated due to a lot of the nomenclature being changed. So I'm providing an updated version of the answer based on the latest Swift frameworks.

**Image Picker Controller:**

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
   //getting details of image
   let uploadFileURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.referenceURL] as! NSURL
           
   let imageName = uploadFileURL.lastPathComponent
   let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first! as String
           
   // getting local path
   let localPath = (documentDirectory as NSString).appendingPathComponent(imageName!)
               
   //getting actual image
   let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
   let data = image.pngData()
   let imageData = image.pngData()! as NSData
   
   let photoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: localPath)
    
   self.uploadFileURL = photoURL
   self.uploadImage(inputData: imageData)
      do {
           let result = try data?.write(to: photoURL as URL, options: .atomic)
       } catch let error {
           print(error)
       }
   picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Upload Image:**

A quick note on upload image. I hashed my filenames. This is not a necessary step, but I highly recommend to do so in the production stage just to ensure no filenames conflict in your S3 bucket.

```
func uploadImage(inputData: NSData) {
        
    //defining bucket and upload file name
    let S3BucketName: String = "your_bucket_name"
    
    let hashed = SHA256.hash(data: inputData)
    let S3UploadKeyName: String = hashed.compactMap { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
    
    let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()
            
    expression.progressBlock = {(task: AWSS3TransferUtilityTask, progress: Progress) in
        print(progress.fractionCompleted)
    }
              
    self.uploadCompletionHandler = { (task, error) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            if ((error) != nil){
                print("Failed with error")
                print("Error: \(error!)")
            }
            else{
                print("Success")
            }
        })
    }
              
    let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()
               
    transferUtility.uploadFile(self.uploadFileURL! as URL, bucket: S3BucketName, key: S3UploadKeyName, contentType: "image/jpeg", expression: expression, completionHandler: uploadCompletionHandler).continueWith { (task) -> AnyObject? in
        if let error = task.error {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        if let _ = task.result {
            print("Upload Starting!")
            // Do something with uploadTask.
        }
        
        return nil
    }
}
```