# Slow image uploading on s3 via iOS amazon sdk

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3, grand-central-dispatch

Uploading images on multiple threads on s3 via amazon SDK takes a hell lot of time. Let me know if you are facing the same problem and found any solution.

Comment: What did you try? add some code, What difficulty in that

Comment: Please try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/35240318/10150796

Answer (score 2):

Without your code, it is difficult to answer this. But as you said that it takes a lot of time to upload, I think your issue is with the size of the image. When you pick an image from an iPhone, the image quality is high. Its high resolution and file size is the reason for slow uploading. So before uploading to AWS bucket, compress the image and reduce the resolution as per your requirement.

When you pick the image,

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let documentsPath = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
        let imagePath = documentsPath?.appendingPathComponent("image.jpg")

        // extract image from the picker and save it
        if let pickedImage = self.scale(image: (info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage)!, toLessThan: 320) {

            let imageData = pickedImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)
            try! imageData!.write(to: imagePath!)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.imgProfileImageView.image = pickedImage
            }


        }
        picker.dismiss(animated: true) {
        }
    }
```

You can reduce the resolution by using this function

```
private func scale(image originalImage: UIImage, toLessThan maxResolution: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
    guard let imageReference = originalImage.cgImage else { return nil }

    let rotate90 = CGFloat.pi/2.0 // Radians
    let rotate180 = CGFloat.pi // Radians
    let rotate270 = 3.0*CGFloat.pi/2.0 // Radians

    let originalWidth = CGFloat(imageReference.width)
    let originalHeight = CGFloat(imageReference.height)
    let originalOrientation = originalImage.imageOrientation

    var newWidth = originalWidth
    var newHeight = originalHeight

    if originalWidth > maxResolution || originalHeight > maxResolution {
        let aspectRatio: CGFloat = originalWidth / originalHeight
        newWidth = aspectRatio > 1 ? maxResolution : maxResolution * aspectRatio
        newHeight = aspectRatio > 1 ? maxResolution / aspectRatio : maxResolution
    }

    let scaleRatio: CGFloat = newWidth / originalWidth
    var scale: CGAffineTransform = .init(scaleX: scaleRatio, y: -scaleRatio)
    scale = scale.translatedBy(x: 0.0, y: -originalHeight)

    var rotateAndMirror: CGAffineTransform

    switch originalOrientation {
    case .up:
        rotateAndMirror = .identity

    case .upMirrored:
        rotateAndMirror = .init(translationX: originalWidth, y: 0.0)
        rotateAndMirror = rotateAndMirror.scaledBy(x: -1.0, y: 1.0)

    case .down:
        rotateAndMirror = .init(translationX: originalWidth, y: originalHeight)
        rotateAndMirror = rotateAndMirror.rotated(by: rotate180 )

    case .downMirrored:
        rotateAndMirror = .init(translationX: 0.0, y: originalHeight)
        rotateAndMirror = rotateAndMirror.scaledBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

    case .left:
        (newWidth, newHeight) = (newHeight, newWidth)
        rotateAndMirror = .init(translationX: 0.0, y: originalWidth)
        rotateAndMirror = rotateAndMirror.rotated(by: rotate270)
        scale = .init(scaleX: -scaleRatio, y: scaleRatio)
        scale = scale.translatedBy(x: -originalHeight, y: 0.0)

    case .leftMirrored:
        (newWidth, newHeight) = (newHeight, newWidth)
        rotateAndMirror = .init(translationX: originalHeight, y: originalWidth)
        rotateAndMirror = rotateAndMirror.scaledBy(x: -1.0, y: 1.0)
        rotateAndMirror = rotateAndMirror.rotated(by: rotate270)

    case .right:
        (newWidth, newHeight) = (newHeight, newWidth)
        rotateAndMirror = .init(translationX: originalHeight, y: 0.0)
        rotateAndMirror = rotateAndMirror.rotated(by: rotate90)
        scale = .init(scaleX: -scaleRatio, y: scaleRatio)
        scale = scale.translatedBy(x: -originalHeight, y: 0.0)

    case .rightMirrored:
        (newWidth, newHeight) = (newHeight, newWidth)
        rotateAndMirror = .init(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
        rotateAndMirror = rotateAndMirror.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi/2.0)
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
    context.concatenate(scale)
    context.concatenate(rotateAndMirror)
    context.draw(imageReference, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: originalWidth, height: originalHeight))
    let copy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return copy
}
```