# How to upload image on AWS in iOS?

Tags: image, amazon-web-services, upload, endpoint, bucket

```
AWSStaticCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSStaticCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithAccessKey:@"AKIA..........." secretKey:@"6FuqRt................."];

AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionEUWest2 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
self.transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];

NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"qr" ofType:@"jpeg"];
AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
uploadRequest.bucket = @"my-flologic-bucket";
uploadRequest.key = @"monday.jpeg";
uploadRequest.body = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

[[self.transferManager upload:uploadRequest] continueWithExecutor:[AWSExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock:^id(AWSTask *task)
{
    if (task.error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"The file uploaded successfully.");

    }
    return nil;
}];
```

ERROR:

> Bucket=my-flologic-bucket,
>   Endpoint=my-flologic-bucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com, Message=The
>   bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the
>   specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.,
>   Code=PermanentRedirect, RequestId=E7471ACE4D6049F8}

Comment: How does your endpoint look like? Is it set up correctly? Please provide the related code (cover confidential parts if necessary)

Comment: I edited my code please check ,i try to reslove please  @ Lepidopteron.Thank you

Comment: Which Endpoint is assigned to your bucket? I am not too familiar with AWS, but it seems like there is a certain endpoint you should use, when you specify this bucket. Besides: This Answer says, that there once was trouble with uploading images the way you currently do to AWS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369602/how-to-upload-a-uiimage-to-s3-with-aws-ios-sdk-v2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the regions and endpoints document from [AWS Regions and Endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region), below region endpoints are valid for S3 us-west-2:

- s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
- s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
- s3.dualstack.us-west-2.amazonaws.com

Can you try using `https://<bucket-name>.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` instead of s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com. I understand s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com is also valid, but I've always used the previous one without any issues.