# Upload image to S3 with Amazon Educate Starter Account

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3

I just want to upload an image to S3, but I am using AWS Educate Account and I'm trying since 4 hours to get this done and have ZERO ideas what isn't working correctly.

So I've set up everything on the AWS console and the bucket is public to EVERYONE + Region US West N.Virginia like it should be with AWS Educate Accounts.

**So here is my code:**

```
        let accessKey = "accessKey"
        let secretKey = "secretKey"
        let credentialsProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey: accessKey, secretKey: secretKey)
        let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
        AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

        let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()
        let bucketname = "bucketname"
        let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()

        transferUtility.uploadData(jpegData, bucket: bucketname, key: "myTransferUtilityUpload.jpg", contentType: "image/jpg", expression: expression) { (task, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

            if let response = task.response {
                print(response)
            }
        }
```

Can anyone tell me what I do wrong?

I get this error message:

> The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (com.amazonaws.AWSS3TransferUtilityErrorDomain error 2.)

**accessKey + secretKey** I got from Account Details + AWS CLI on the 'Welcome to AWS Educate Starter Account' Dashboard and obviously the bucket name is the same name like in my console

**EDIT:**

```
if let jpegData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.7) {

        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        if let documentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory,
                                                    in: .userDomainMask).first {
            var sourceFolderURL =  documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("image.jpg")

            do {
                try jpegData.write(to: sourceFolderURL)
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completionHandler(nil)
                return
            }

            let accessKey = "-"
            let secretKey = "-"
            let bucketname = "-"
            let credentialsProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey: accessKey, secretKey: secretKey)
            let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
            AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration


            let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()!
            uploadRequest.body = sourceFolderURL
            uploadRequest.key = "image.jpg"
            uploadRequest.bucket = bucketname
            uploadRequest.contentType = "image/jpeg"
            uploadRequest.acl = .publicReadWrite

            let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()

            transferManager.upload(uploadRequest).continueWith { [weak self] (task) -> Any? in
                if let error = task.error {
                    print("Upload failed with error: (\(error.localizedDescription))")
                    completionHandler(nil)
                    return nil
                }

                if task.result != nil {
                    let url = AWSS3.default().configuration.endpoint.url
                    let publicURL = url?.appendingPathComponent(uploadRequest.bucket!).appendingPathComponent(uploadRequest.key!)
                    if let absoluteString = publicURL?.absoluteString {
                        print("Uploaded to:\(absoluteString)")
                        completionHandler(nil)
                    }
                }
                completionHandler(nil)
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If this is just a one-off need, you could use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 cp` command to upload the files. Oh, and is the bucket also in us-east-1?

Comment: yes in order to use the AWS Starter Account you can only use N. Virginia (USEast1)

Comment: Does it work if you use the AWS CLI to copy the files? This will be a good test of access permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have uploaded an image to S3 bucket with the following code:
First, save the image to a temporary directory.

```
func uploadImageToS3(imageName:String, completion:@escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

    let accessKey = "accessKey"
    let secretKey = "secretKey"

    let credentialsProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey: accessKey, secretKey: secretKey)
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:AWSRegionType.APSoutheast2, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)

    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

    let S3BucketName = "bucketname"

    let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()!
    uploadRequest.body = self.getImageURLWithName(imageName:imageName)
    uploadRequest.key = "\(imageName)"
    uploadRequest.bucket = S3BucketName
    uploadRequest.contentType = "image/jpeg"

    //You can specify private or public here
    uploadRequest.acl = .private

    let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()

    transferManager.upload(uploadRequest).continueWith { [weak self] (task) -> Any? in
        ProgressIndicatorHelper.hideGlobalHUD()
        if let error = task.error {
            print("Upload failed with error: (\(error.localizedDescription))")
            completion(false)
        }

        if task.result != nil {
            let url = AWSS3.default().configuration.endpoint.url
            let publicURL = url?.appendingPathComponent(uploadRequest.bucket!).appendingPathComponent(uploadRequest.key!)
            if let absoluteString = publicURL?.absoluteString {
                print("Uploaded to:\(absoluteString)")
                completion(true)
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

For getting image from Path following code I have used:

```
 func getImageURLWithName(imageName:String) -> URL {
        var sourceImageURL: URL!
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        if let documentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory,
                                                    in: .userDomainMask).first {
            var sourceFolderURL:URL!

            sourceFolderURL =  documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("YourTempFolder")

            sourceImageURL = sourceFolderURL.appendingPathComponent(imageName)

        }
        return sourceImageURL
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Moreover: Right now I don't think you can directly upload image from memory.
I searched for it. Following are links for same:
https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/42

[How to upload a UIImage to S3 with AWS iOS SDK v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369602/how-to-upload-a-uiimage-to-s3-with-aws-ios-sdk-v2)

Let me know if you find any error.

Comment: So if I have the image as an UIImage/JPG Representation data, you mean I should save it to a file and then proceed they way you did it?

Comment: Yes. I did the same. And I shared few links in which people are saying that from memory image cannot be uploaded. you can refer those links before proceeding.

Comment: yes read them I'll try it thank you already I'll come back if I (hopefully) finished successful ^^

Comment: sure. Let me know if you face any problem

Comment: I made the changes but now i get the same error code with a different number: (com.amazonaws.AWSServiceErrorDomain error 13.) -> see edit for my code.

Comment: it says Message=The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records., but i COPIED it from the labs.vocareum.com site -> Account Details ??

Comment: i just checked that aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key change every time i load the page new ?? i'm getting more and more confused by this ..

Comment: I just used AWSStaticCredentialsProvider() instead of passing the access key and secret key and know it works I am in confusion, but whatever it works thanks to you.
Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a policy issue?
Try attaching this policy to your bucket (bucket policies)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*"
            ]
        }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Be VERY careful! This will give the entire world access to your bucket, including permission to upload and delete content. Not a good idea from a security and billing standpoint.

Comment: Yes I know but my priority is to make it working for now, and anyways it's just for training purpose and has no critical data whatsoever^^

Comment: This was just for testing purposes only, I should have said that :)